# Without using a third variable at all, swap X and Y values

Tags: javascript, optimization

```
var x=10;
var y=5;
```

Solution 1

```
x= x + y 
y= x - y 
x= x - y
```

Solution 2

```
x=y+x,y=x-y,x=x-y;
```

the two solutions are equal to each other but the second one is faster, why?

Can anyone show me the optimized opcode generated for both solutions by JS engine?

Comment: Solution 1 & Solution 2 is same code.

Comment: Watch out if you are expecting integer arithmetic and x and y are of v.large magnitude - since x + y could exceed the integer range.

Comment: Apart from that, speed might depend on using the += and -= operators (it used to in C) x += y; y = x - y; x -= y;

Comment: As expected, the assertion that one is faster is simply wrong: http://jsperf.com/two-ways-of-swapping

Comment: No, this isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript. Actually **read** the question above, it's about optimization and why would is faster than the other. (It's wrong, but not a duplicate.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a mistaken assumption.

Comment: you are right.. same speed, and this is the generated opCode
    movl $10, -4(%rbp)
movl -4(%rbp), %eax
addl %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl -4(%rbp), %eax
movl -8(%rbp), %edx
subl %eax, %edx
movl %edx, %eax
movl %eax, -4(%rbp)
movl -4(%rbp), %eax
subl %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl $0, %eax

Comment: @nullException: Well, that's what it is with one specific JavaScript compiler. There are several different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Ecmascript 6 you can do:

```
var x=10;
var y=5;

[x,y] = [y,x]
console.log(x,y) // 5, 10
```

If not, here is already a good way: [How to swap two variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript)

As for the 2 methods you have, doubt they are different, you should first try to check whether there is a big time difference with multiple tests

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any meaningful difference in performance for either solution or using XOR. Non on the test are consistently faster so I assume the premise of the question is incorrect.

```
JSLitmus.test('Solution1', function() {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 5;    
    x = x + y;
    y = x - y;
    x = x - y;
});

JSLitmus.test('Solution2', function() {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 5;
    x = y + x, y = x - y, x = x - y;
});

JSLitmus.test('Solution3', function() {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 5;
    x ^= y;
    y ^= x;
    x ^= y;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6L0d6rpn/