# javascript function to swap two variables

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, swap

```
function swap(x,y){
  var t=x;
  x=y;
  y=t;
}
```

This won't work. when you `swap(a,b)`, variable `a` and `b` get copied into the function and whatever happens in that function doesn't affect the real value of `a` and `b`. I want something like this:

```
 (function(){
 a=1;
 b=2;
 function swap(){//something}
 swap(a,b);
 console.log(a) //2
 console.log(b) //1
 })()
```

How to do this?

Comment: In JS scalar variables are passed **by value**, not reference. So.. you _can't_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap two variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swap() function for variables's values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165189/swap-function-for-variabless-values)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the latest version of JavaScript (ES2015), then you can use the new language feature called "destructuring".  You don't need a function.  It looks like this:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

// swap!
[b, a] = [a, b];
```

If you want a function, you can do it like this:

```
function swap(a, b) {
  return [b, a]
}

[a, b] = swap(a, b);
```

Looking at this code, I kind of prefer the function, though it is a bit superfluous.  I like how expressive it is.  You aren't left puzzling over what the code does.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Arguments are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), even in the case of objects. It's just that the value passed for them is a reference to the object.

Basically this means that any arguments you receive have no actual connection to the original variables you passed in except that they may share a reference.

Imagine you've written `a` and `b` on a piece of paper. In JS, the only way to share those values with a function is to copy them on to a *different* piece of paper and hand it to the function. So even if that function scratches out `a` on the new piece of paper and replaces it with `b`, it doesn't change what you have written on the original piece of paper.

In short, it is not possible to change the value of a variable which was used as an argument for a function.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a variable outside the scope of the function so you can use it inside the function, this is something you can do:

```
<head>
<script>var x=0, y=1;</script>
</head>

<script>
function swap()
{
  var t = x;
  x = y;
  y = t;
} 
</script>
```

or even this works

```
<script>
var x=0; y=1;
function swap(id1, id2)
{
  var t = x;
  x = y;
  y = t;
} 
console.log(x+"  "+y);
</script>
```

I used this quite a lot and works fine. the `x` and `y` can be taken from any where and will work inside a function no problem.
you can also do

```
function(id1, id2)
{
  x=document.getElementById(id1);
  y=document.getElementById(id2);

  var t = x.value;
  x.value = y.value;
  y.value = t;

}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is you can only swap those two variables. It doesn't allow you to swap any other variables.

Comment: what is it that you need exactly? you can set the x and y to be anything.. you can set hidden inputs with values or save the data you need inside an array, but passing the values to a a function and it makes changes to them is not possible. 
check my edit

Comment: What I mean is lets say I wanted to swap `x` and `y` at one point then swap `w` and `z` at a different point. This function doesn't let me do that. I can only swap those two variables instead of two arbitrary variables.

Comment: like i said, you can only work around it.. where do you get the x y and z data from? you can implement their values in the actual HTML, for example inside an array or in the `<option value="VAL">` attribute if you are using a `<select>`, you can put them in `<input type="hidden" value="VAL">`, you can only work around it.
those `x,y,z` come from somewhere,  just get them directly by passing a parameter to the function stating their positions.. like pass the IDs for the elements or their positions in the array.

Comment: if you prove more information on the actual problem then I would be able to help you on a workaround, but trying to do it the way you asked about won't work.

Comment: I'm not OP. I was just pointing out a shortcoming of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers above, Arguments are only passed by value. If you really need to achieve the swap, you can use the 2 variables algorithm:

```
var a = 10, b = 20;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
console.log (a+" "+b); // 20 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function swap(value) {
    value.first = value.first + value.second;
    value.second = value.first - value.second;
    value.first = value.first - value.second; 
}

// declared an object named value which has two keys - first and second corresponding to the first and the second values respectively

var value = {
    first: 1,
    second: 2
}

console.log(value.first, value.second) // prints 1 2
swap(value);
console.log(value.first, value.second); // prints 2 1
```