# swap() function for variables's values

Tags: javascript, function, variables, swap

I am not able to achieve the desired result for this swap function below, where I want the values printed as 3,2

```
function swap(x,y){
 var t = x;
 x = y;
 y = t;
}

console.log(swap(2,3));
```

Any clue will be appreciated !

Comment: It does swap your variables, but that's about it, it doesn't return anything, and the variables are local to the function ?

Comment: there is no `return [x,y];`

Comment: Why not just swap the variables without using a function?

Answer (score 8):

Your function is swapping the values internally, but the function does not return a value.

The following method returns an array of values in reverse order of what was supplied.

```js
function swap(x, y) {
    var t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
    return [x, y];
}

console.log(swap(2, 3));
```

However, you could easily do something like the following snippet, because - based on your supplied code - there seems to be no need to actually swap the values of the arguments.

```js
function swap(x, y) {
    return [y, x];
}

console.log(swap(2, 3));
```

Comment: Mind explaining why this works?

Comment: First snippet or second snippet? @AndrewLi

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need the values to swap:

```
function swap (x, y)
{
  return [y, x];
}
```

If you do need the values to swap, but you don't want to declare another variable:

```
function swap (x, y)
{
  x = x + y;
  y = x - y;
  x = x - y;
  return [x, y];
}
```

Comment: The second algorithm will not swap strings. Besides, it comes from an era when RAM memory was an issue. It shouldn't be used for modern JS apps.

Comment: y = [x, x = y][0]; one line solution