# swap values in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've two variables and i wanna swap them without using third variable.

Ex:

```
let a = 'value1',
    b = 'value2';
```

Result:

```
a = 'value2',
b = 'value1'
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. But telling you how would defeat the purpose of the assignment I think. Besides, this is easily googleable.

Comment: @FelixKling Unfortunately the ES6 answer in that dup is well-hidden down past the old accepted answer. I wonder if it would be better to re-open this, give it a modern answer, then mark the other question as a dup of this one, since believe it or not I can not find any other questions on the topic here.

Comment: @FelixKling this is es6 question not a normal javascript.

Comment: All the suggestions in the duplicate are valid in ES6 as well, it even has ES6 specific solutions, you just have to look through the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25910841/218196

Comment: Huh finally i found the best way for swapping variables value in ES6. i'm going to use new feature of ES6 called destructuring. using destructuring: `let a = 'value1',  b='value2';     [a, b] = [b, a];` and it's done.