# How to write a swap function in javascript (variable name as string input)

Tags: javascript, swap

For example,

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
swap ('x', 'y');
console.log (x); // 2
console.log (y); // 1
```

The swapped value may be not a simple variable

[How to swap two variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript) doesn't require to have a calling, so it differs from this question.

---

Solved. I didn't know that the ref of left of = is evaled before the right is calculated

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The problem is that javascript can't use pointers and can't modify the variable by a reference to it.

Comment: +David Archibald So I made the arguments in string

Comment: @l4m2 please use `@` to tag someone.

Comment: I don't quite understand how using a string would help, but as it is now closed, I will drop it.

Comment: @David Archibald For simple value at least can write function swap(a,b){eval('A=[B,B=A][0]'.replace('A',a).replace('B',b))}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function swap(x, y) {
  return [y, x]
}

[x, y] = swap(x, y);
```

Comment: It changes the calling of swap

Answer (score 0):

For global variables, you could use the `window` object with the names as key.

```js
function swap(a, b) {
    var temp = window[a];
    window[a] = window[b];
    window[b] = temp;
}

var x = 1,
    y = 2;

swap ('x', 'y');
console.log (x); // 2
console.log (y); // 1
```

Comment: But not for variables in function

Comment: Its a bad practice polluting window. Why would you suggest it. Also, this is a  duplicate. We should not answer duplicates as most of the approaches have been answered and have comments/ explanations for better understanding

Comment: i think the question is for educational purpose, as this answer. in real working environment, the problem is not solvable, because of the limited usage.