# Swap the values of two variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a variable called `foo` set to the object: `{example: '2', anotherExample: '1'}` and another variable called `anotherFoo` set to `'orange'` how would I swap the values of `foo` and `anotherFoo`? This would mean that `foo = 'orange'` and `anotherFoo = {example: '2', anotherExample: '1'}`.

Comment: Please show what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap two variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an intermediate variable to hold the value of one.

```
var a = 1
var b = 2

var c = a
a = b
b = c
```

You can use a method shown in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16201730/4216035) but in my opinion is not very readable.

Comment: The big plus for this method is that it works in other languages, and it's very clear to new comers how it's done.

Comment: Agreed. At my company we focus on making sure our code is easy to "reason about" because scaling your software is not just about growing your user base but growing your team as well. The less kludgy the better. Thought as a developer, the cool shortcuts are very fun to use :)

Comment: It's also markedly more efficient than using structuring/desctructuring. See [which way to swap two variable values is more optimised?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55257300/5217142)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ES6+ try this:

```
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

Otherwise:

```
b = [a, a = b][0];
```

Comment: Great use for ES6 :)

Comment: I'm glad you liked it %)

Answer (score 0):

```
let foo = {
  example: '2',
  anotherExample: '1'
};

let anotherFoo = 'orange';
```

First, use a dummy variable to store the original value of one variable:

```
const dummy = anotherFoo;
```

Then, overwrite that variable with the original value of the second variable:

```
anotherFoo = Object.assign({}, foo);
```

Finally, overwrite the second variable with the original value of the first variable, which happens to be stored in the dummy variable:

```
foo = dummy;
```