# which way to swap two variable values is more optimised?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, swap, destructuring

The methods are about swapping of two variables in javaScript.

Method 1:

```
var a=0,b=1,c=a;

a = b;

b = c;
```

Method 2:

```
var [a,b] = [0,1];

[a,b] = [b,a];
```

Comment: Which javascript engine? It makes a HUGE difference

Comment: method 1 is just the assignment of variables but method 2 includes destructuring of the array with assignments. so surely the 1st one is optimized.

Comment: You know, that "deep down", two memory records can not be exchanged without using a third memory record. So the best Method 2 could do is to run in Method 1 style, no matter what symbols and syntactic sugar you use.

Comment: Just set up performance tests yourself and check it. Also first method will be significantly faster as pointed out by @AZ_. https://jsperf.com/js-permutation/1 I set up tests for you this time (this website's server is slow af btw, but that doesn't affects the tests).

Comment: @IvanKuckir The XOR trick works without a third memory locations. It's typically slower than moving data around on modern processor architectures though, where registers are cheap.

Comment: context of the code has a big impact - code 1 is at least 5x faster - but in some contexts, code 1 can be 200x faster - not because code 2 becomes slower, but because code 1 becomes exponentially faster ... either way, code 1 is always going to win hands down

Comment: @IvanKuckir not *completely* true. A very simple way to swap `a` and `b` without a third variable is `a += b; b = a - b; a -= b;` (to illustrate with `0, 1` this turns into `a = 0 + 1; b = 1 - 1; a = 1 - 0;` that will swap two numeric values without using a third variable. It has its own problems, of course but it just demonstrates the possibility. For a general case (e.g., if you want to swap strings or object references), you'd need a third variable, true and you probably never really need to cut down on the spare variable in JS.

Comment: @Bergi  @VLAZ  I think it depends a lot on terminology. In `a = a + b`, where is the temporary result of the right side `(a+b)` stored, before it is assigned to `a` (many may call it a "temporary third location"). But you are right, if we talk about instructions and registers of modern CPUs, it can be done without using a third register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can see by yourself.

Change the `NUMBER_OF_TIMES` as you would like.

Also run it as many times as you want to get the average.

```js
let NUMBER_OF_TIMES = 1000000
console.time("Method1")
for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TIMES; i++) {
  var a = 0, b = 1, c = a;
  a = b;
  b = c;
}
console.timeEnd("Method1")
console.time("Method2")
for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TIMES; i++) {
  var [a, b] = [0, 1];
  [a, b] = [b, a];
}
console.timeEnd("Method2")
```