# How can I use array destructuring when there's no array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck at this task. How can I use array destructuring to change the three statements below into 1 statement?

The main reason for my confusion is that a and b are already declared. And there is no array.

´´´

```
(function UseArrayDestructuring2() {
        let a = 1;
        let b = 2;
        
        // Use array destructuring to change the 3 statements below into 1 statement.
        // You should not need a temporary variable anymore.
        let tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp; 

        // Don't make changes below this line   
        
        expect(a).toEqual(2);
        expect(b).toEqual(1);
```

´´´

Comment: You can *make* an array then destructure it.

Comment: This looks like a code assessment...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to swap two variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript) ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910841/479156) specifically.)

Answer (score 4):

You could collect the values in an array and destructure the array to the swiched variables.

This approach creates still a temporary value.

```
[b, a] = [a, b];
```

Comment: It creates a temporary *value*, the array, but no additional *variables*.